# Who said "Poetry is the art of giving different names to the same thing"?

Tags: poetry, quote-source

[Over on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40302/was-there-a-person-made-the-quote-about-poetry-that-poincar%C3%A9-responded-to/40304#40304), Laurel found some partial information in a [quote from *Mathematics as a culture clue and other essays*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3K24AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22poetry+is+the+art+of+giving%22+the+same+name+to+different+things&q=%22quoted+that+mot+to+a+poet%22&redir_esc=y):

> I once quoted that *mot* to a poet, and got the quick response:
> "Poetry is the art of giving different names to the same thing."

Do we know which poet?

The *mot* was made by mathematician Poincaré in his essay [The future of mathematics](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Poincare_Future/): "Mathematics is the art of giving the same name to different things."
Follow up: [Is poetry the art of giving different names to the same thing?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5220/1015)

Comment: I suspect that the second one was made up by somebody after the fact. The [original Poincare quote](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Extras/Poincare_Future.html) doesn't imply (to me) that that's what he had in mind. He was speaking somewhat technically on the nature of how mathematical reasoning works. It's serious, not self-deprecating. And it's a poor description of poetry. Which makes me think that somebody was inspired by the Poincare quote and used it to derive a disparaging statement about poetry.

Comment: Maybe he just picked that idea in his article to form the quote, or simply forgot the second one? And what's the better description of poetry?

Comment: See also [this answer on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/7190/61630) (and the comment on it). @JoshuaEngel It's a poor description of mathematics, as well as a poor description of poetry :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor can you explain why it's a poor description on math and poetry?

Comment: @Ooker There's a lot more to poetry than giving different names to the same thing, and there's a lot more to mathematics than giving the same name to different things. In fact, giving the same name to different things is *bad* mathematics (abuse of notation/terminology).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest occurrence I could find through the snippet view of Google Books dates from 1935:

> I once quoted that *mot* to a poet, and got the quick response:
> “*Poetry is the art of giving different names to the same thing.*”
> Perhaps mathematics and poetry are but clashing aspects of a single Art.

(Source: [*Scripta Mathematica: A Quarterly Journal Devoted to the Philosophy, History, and Expository Treatment of Mathematics*, volume 3 (1935)](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Scripta_Mathematica/uzg5AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=poetry+%22different+names%22+%22the+same+thing%22&dq=poetry+%22different+names%22+%22the+same+thing%22&printsec=frontcover), page 305.)

For full context, see the essay "Three Great Synonyms: Relation, Transformation, Function" in [*The Collected Works of Cassius Jackson Keyser: Volume 1: Mathematics as a Culture Clue and Other Essays*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/The_Collected_Works_of_Cassius_Jackson_K/JNjuAAAAMAAJ) (New York: Scripta Mathematica, Yeshiva University, 1947):

> Of the many pithy sayings of Henri Poincaré perhaps none is btter that this:
> “*Mathematics is the art of giving the same name to different things.*”
> I once quoted that *mot* to a poet, and got the quick response:
> “*Poetry is the art of giving different names to the same thing.*”
> Perhaps mathematics and poetry are but clashing aspects of a single Art.

The poet remains anonymous, both here and in other sources. [*777 Mathematical Conversation Starters*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/777_Mathematical_Conversation_Starters/JNbKURWmODkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=poetry+%22different+names%22+%22same+thing%22&pg=PA193&printsec=frontcover) by John de Pillis (2002) identifies the sources as "anonymous". [*Mathematics, Poetry And Beauty*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Mathematics_Poetry_And_Beauty/Iw63CgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=poetry+%22different+names%22+%22same+thing%22&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover) by Ron Aharoni (2014) does not provide an author either.

The quote is such a poor characterisation of poetry that it is not to be taken seriously. However, if the quote is real, it is not obvious which poet might have said it.
The list of [authors who were at Columbia University at some point in time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Columbia_University_people#Literature_2) does not provide a credible match. (Gabriela Mistral only fits timewise.) Among the list of related people on the page about [Cassius Jackson Keyser papers, 1884-1945](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/lweb/archival/collections/ldpd_4078985/) at the Columbia University Library, only [Clarence Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarence_Day) published some poems. According to Wikipedia,

> Day achieved lasting fame in literary circles for his comment "The world of books is the most remarkable creation of man. Nothing else that he builds ever lasts. Monuments fall, nations perish, civilizations grow old and die out; and, after an era of darkness, new races build others. But in the world of books are volumes that have seen this happen again and again, and yet live on, still young, still as fresh as the day they were written, still telling men's hearts of the hearts of men centuries dead."

This is not really a quip, so it is not clear whether Day might be the sort of person who may come up with idea Keyser attributes to an anonymous poet.

The closest similarity in wording is the following quote from a [1929 issue of *The Essex Review*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+essex+poet%22+%22different+names%22+%22the+same+thing%22&biw=1920&bih=875&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1946&tbm=bks&ei=yD_ZYpD0CJeqxc8Pw-yN8AM&ved=0ahUKEwiQ-O6r94n5AhUXVfEDHUN2Az44ChDh1QMICA&uact=5&oq=%22the+essex+poet%22+%22different+names%22+%22the+same+thing%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ_AlY-DJghjloAHAAeACAAYcBiAHvC5IBBDAuMTOYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books), which I could only access through the snippet view of Google Books (emphasis mine):

> The Essex poet, as we see, was never in want of words. **He has quite a number of different names for the same things**, each name expressing a different view of that thing.

(The snippet mentions the name Brithnoth, aka [Byrhtnoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byrhtnoth), who died at the Battle of Maldon (991), which took place at or near Maldon, Essex. See the Old-English poem [The Battle of Maldon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_of_Maldon).) Altough giving different names to the same thing may be something one specific poet did, it is not something that characterises all poetry.

Going out on a limb, one might even claim Keyser misheard the words "Polyonymy is the art of giving different names to the same thing", since [polyonymy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/polyonymy) refers to "the use of many names for the same thing or person".

---

I have also found the statement ["Poetry and Religion are but different names for the same things"](https://www.google.de/books/edition/The_Christian_remembrancer_or_The_Church/2PkDAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=poetry+%22different+names%22+%22the+same+thing%22&pg=PA605&printsec=frontcover) (in *The Christian remembrancer; or, The Churchman's Biblical, ecclesiastical & literary miscellany*, 1842). Since it is not clear why anyone would quote such a claim in response to a quote about mathematics, this does not seem a valid source.